# Why React component rendering done only once, but the reduce-action changes the state multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

I have React component, which connects to **WebSocket** server inside `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { connectWs } = this.props
    connectWs(
        true,
        () => {},
        () => {},
        res => {
            this.socketCallback(res)
        },
    )
}

socketCallback = payload => {
    const { handleClaimSuccess } = this.props
    const { horse_id, race_id } = payload
    const data = {
        'horseId': horse_id,
        'raceId': race_id
    }

    handleClaimSuccess(data)
}

render() {
    const { claimed } = this.props
    return (
        <div>
            {claimed.map((data, index) => (
                <div className="primary-text">
                     { data.isPending ? 'PENDING' : 'COLLECTED' }
                </div>
            )}
        <div>
    )
}
```

The server sends 3 messages via sockets, which component handles and sends to **reducer** for updating the state. The time difference between that 3 messages is 30-60 microsecond.

```
'handleClaimSuccess': (state, { payload }) => {
    if (payload) {
        const { horseId, raceId } = payload
        const updatedWinnings = state.userWinnings

        const indexOfWinningInClaimed = findIndex(updatedWinnings.claimed, {
            'horseId': horseId,
            'race': {
                'raceId': raceId
            },
        })

        updatedWinnings.claimed[indexOfWinningInClaimed].isPending = false

        return {
            ...state,
            'userWinnings': updatedWinnings
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

All messages change the state accordingly, but component renders results only once (after 1st message) and ignore next 2 messages.

As I understand its related to small interval of messages, cause it works fine with single messages.

How it can handle all 3 messages and render the state after each message?

Comment: the connectWs props is async function maybe?

Comment: @Jerome no its used for connecting to WebSocket server. For single messages everything works fine, issue happened only for multiple messages with small time delay.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the update state of React, react only promises that it will change the data. The update state is not updated every time you send different data, multiple updates can be combined into one and mass update 1 time. In your case, you update the state 3 times, so react combined this into one and only did it 1 time.

From React's [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

updateState does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to updateState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Comment: I use redux-actions for changing the store, not setState. Also the messages length may be 5, 7 or 1, so there are no constant count of WS messages.